How to remove a shadow/reflection in Render?
I am trying to render the simulation of underwater. I placed an ocean modifier at the top and used a transparent cube for this. However, in the render, there is some shadow. Does anybody know how to remove this shadow? I appreciate your help in advance. I drew a red circle around the shadow in the attached picture that I want to be removed.
Thank you!


We can't guess your scene setup, objects, materials, lighting, possible compositing ... You'd need to provide more informations than that.
